# ajax php form validation not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have written a php file and jquery to retrieve data from a database and validate on a textfield blur event to check the typed value is whether available or not. Below are my code:

On form php:

```
<script>
        $("#catname").blur(function() {
            $.post("./scripts/checkavailability.php", {
                nameava: $("#catname").val(),
            }, function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });

            var setr = "<?php
                         include './scripts/checkavailability.php';
                         $dbava = getfromdb("name", "tbl_category");
                         $avams = check($txtval, $dbava, "$name");
                         echo $avams;
                         ?>";
            $("#jinx").html(setr);

        });
    </script>
```

checkavalilability.php :

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['nameava'])) {
$txtval = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nameava']);
}


function getfromdb($field, $table) {
$avres = mysql_query("SELECT `" . $field . "` FROM `" . $table . "`");
return $avres;
}

function check($curval, $qres, $s_field) {
while ($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($qres)) {
    $dbval = $a_row[$s_field];

    if ($curval == $dbval) {
        return "This value is taken";
        break;
    } else {
        return "This value is available";
    }
}
}

?>
```

Note: catname is the textfield id and jinx is the div id.

Comment: where are you calling getfromdb and check function in your php file

Comment: no. i don't get any errors. i get nothing. and i called check and getfromdb functions inside the javascript code. that is the first code.

Comment: Where is `$name` coming from?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger : thanx. that was a mistake. it should be "name", and that's the table's field name. but that didn't fix the problem.

Comment: As far as I see, your `$.post` is doing nothing, why not pass all these values (`tbl_category`,`tbl_category`) as parameters to the `$.post` and call the functions inside `if (isset($_POST['nameava']))`

Comment: k. i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying something like this:

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $("#catname").blur(function() {
        $.post("./scripts/checkavailability.php", {
            nameava: $("#catname").val(),
        }, function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#jinx").html(data);
        });

    });
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

function getfromdb($field, $table) {
    $avres = mysql_query("SELECT `" . $field . "` FROM `" . $table . "`");
    return $avres;
}

function check($curval, $qres, $s_field) {
    while ($a_row = mysql_fetch_array($qres)) {
        $dbval = $a_row[$s_field];

        if ($curval == $dbval) {
            return "This value is taken";
            //break;
        } else {
            return "This value is available";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['nameava'])) {
    $txtval = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nameava']);
    $dbava = getfromdb("name", "tbl_category");
    $avams = check($txtval, $dbava, "name");
    echo $avams;
}
exit();
?>
```